# adding environment variable to PYTHONPATH in a docker file

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile, pythonpath

I'm trying to dockerize a Django application where I use some custom modules and in order to import them I need to add their path to PYTHONPATH 
the problem is when I try to do it I overwrite the PYTHONPATH so it no longer detects Django.

commands i tried:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTONPATH}:/mypath"

ENV PYTHONPATH "$PYTONPATH:/mypath"

RUN export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/mypath"
```

i also tried to create a .bash_profile file added the path to it and run source .bash_profile but no success :

```
CMD echo "export PYTHONPATH='/mypath'" > ./.bash_profile

CMD source ./.bash_profile
```

the error message:

````
Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?```
````

Comment: How about you install the modules properly with a `setup.py`?

Comment: Please give more info about the docker image.... and consider installing packages from requirements in virtualenv as suggested. You can specify the exact versions by `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: ...in the "system" Python path inside the image; since the image provides isolation the approach @KlausD. suggests avoids needing to change `$PYTHONPATH` at all without conflicting with other things on the system.

Comment: You can also try: `CMD echo "export PYTHONPATH='$PYTHONPATH:/mypath'" > ./.bash_profile`
 and 
`CMD source ./.bash_profile`

Comment: @DavidMaze what I understand is I need to set the python path inside the python script without touching the $PYTHONPATH variable !?

Comment: @mr_mo I've tried your command and no success :(

Comment: You should never need to adjust the Python path from inside the script.  (I think `.` is usually in the default path, which helps.)  If you can `pip install` your application that avoids this problem entirely.